# How to containerize .Net project when using Shared library

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker

So I have a .net app with file structure:

```
-MyApp
   |__Client
   |__Server
   |__Shared
```

Inside ***Shared*** directory I have defined a `model` for users to subscribe.

***Subscriber.cs***

```
public class Subscriber { }
```

Inside ***Client*** directory, I used this *shared* **Subscriber** model.

```
public interface ISubscriberService
{
  IList<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

Inside ***Server*** directory

```
public IEnumerable<Subscriber> Get()
{
   List<Subscriber> subscribers = _unitOfWork.Subscribers.GetAll().ToList();
   return subscribers;
}
```

Now Here's when I ran into problems.

So I needed to ***Dockerize*** *MyApp* project, I placed a ***Dockerfile*** inside client, although this creates a problem, the ***Subscriber*** model is in the *Shared* directory. Its (forbidden path) to `COPY ../Shared .` , nor do I find placing one dockerfile in main directory and specifing ***Client***, ***Server***, and ***Shared*** builds confiuration.

*example:*

```
-MyApp
   |__Client
   |__Server
   |__Shared
   |__Dockerfile
```

My solution facing this problem, was instead of using one docker file, was to use multiple

```
-MyApp
   |__Client
   |__Server
   |__Shared
   |__Dockerfile.Client
   |__Dockerfile.Server
```

Feel like this will allow me more control, when accessing the shared library any sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED***

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  library:
    build:
      context: ./Shared
      dockerfile: dockerfile
  client:
    build:
      context: ./Client
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - library
  server:
    build:
      context: ./Server
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - library
```

So creating a docker-compose file then telling docker directory `depends_on` another directory (shared library) solves it.

***EDIT**

Never mind first solution seem to work correctly wonder if there's another solution where i can place my dockerfiles into the project solution rather then outside then `cd` into it